# Get date from the List of newborn on which the most children were born

Tags: java, list, java-stream, localdate

I have a File.txt (represent `NewBorn`).

I've created a class `NewBorn` that has the following fields: `id`, `name`, `age`.

Then I'm reading the file and parsing it, so I can get a nice output.

From the *list of newborn* (based on *file.txt*) I need to get the date on which the most children were born, but I have a problem filtering through that.

That's what I've tried :

```
public static List<NewBorn> dateInWitchMostChildrenAreBorn(List<NewBorn> newBornList) {
    return newBornList.stream()
            .filter(newBorn -> newBorn.getBirthdate() // in here I tried to go use =  but is not good of course  )
            //then I want to collect that and  count the one that is the most in witch  children are born
            .collect((Collectors.toSet()));
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this method's return type be `Date` not `List<NewBorn>`?

Comment: @HariHaravelan Nope, [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: Indeed, that  is a thing i did not look corectly for :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this
First List  should not be there since you want to return a LocalDate
If your relation between classes is correct this should be working :
Any  question please let me know :)

```
public LocalDate mostCommonDate() {
    Map<LocalDate, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Newborn newborn : newborns) {
        Integer value = map.get(newborn.getBirthday());
        map.put(newborn.getBirthday(), (value == null) ? 1 : value + 1);
    }
    Entry<LocalDate, Integer> max = null;
    for (Entry<LocalDate, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (max == null || max.getValue() > entry.getValue()) {
            max = entry;
        }
    }
    return max.getKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, First filtering the null `birthdate`, then grouping it by birthdate then collecting it to a Map with `birthdate` as key and occurrence as value, then returning the max occurrence `birthdate`

```java
public static LocalDate dateInWitchMostChildrenAreBorn(List<NewBorn> newBornList) {
    return newBornList.stream()
        .filter(newBorn -> Objects.nonNull(newBorn.getBirthdate()))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NewBorn::getBirthdate, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `orElse(null)`, you could also write just `get()`, as the *grouping by* collector guarantees that each group contains at least one element.

Comment: @MCEmperor Could we risk there being no groups?

Comment: @OleV.V. Good point, I hadn't thought about that. But then I would have returned the `Optional<LocalDate>` itself, instead of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be ***multiple dates*** for which the numbers of children have been born are equal. Therefore, there can be more than one date that corresponds to the **maximum** number of newborns. Maybe that's why the method listed in the question is meant to return a *list*.

In order to obtain the `List<LocalDate>` containing all dates when number of newborns is *maximal*, first, we need to create *map* `Map<LocalDate, Long>` (*number of newborns by date*) by using collector `Collectors.groupingBy()`. The *function* that extracts the *birthdate* is used as the first argument and `Collectors.counting()`, that generates the number of elements mapped to a key, as a *downstream collector*.

Then we can generate the resulting list in a ***single pass*** over the entries of this map with a **custom collector** that will collect the entries having the highest *previously encountered* count. If the next entry has a value greater the previous maximum, intermediate results will be cleaned up.

To implement a *custom collector*, we can utilize the static method `of()` defined in the `Collector` interface.

`ArrayDeque` is used as *mutable container* of the collector.

The *finisher function* creates a stream over the resulting *queue*, which extracts date objects from the entries and collect them into a *list*.

```
public static List<LocalDate> dateInWitchMostChildrenAreBorn(List<NewBorn> newBornList) {
    return newBornList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(NewBorn::getBirthdate,
                                           Collectors.counting())) // Map<LocalDate, Long> - number of newborns by date
            .entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    ArrayDeque::new, // supplier
                    (Queue<Map.Entry<LocalDate, Long>> queue,
                     Map.Entry<LocalDate, Long> next) -> { // accumulator
                        if (!queue.isEmpty() && queue.element().getValue() < next.getValue()) queue.clear();
                        if (queue.isEmpty() || queue.element().getValue().equals(next.getValue())) queue.add(next);
                    },
                    (Queue<Map.Entry<LocalDate, Long>> left,
                     Queue<Map.Entry<LocalDate, Long>> right) -> { // combiner
                        if (left.isEmpty()) return right;
                        if (right.isEmpty()) return left;
                        if (left.element().getValue() < right.element().getValue()) return right;
                        if (left.element().getValue() > right.element().getValue()) return left;
                        else {left.addAll(right); return left;}
                    },
                    (Queue<Map.Entry<LocalDate, Long>> queue) -> // finisher
                            queue.stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).toList()
            ));
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<NewBorn> newBorns =
            List.of(new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 5)),
                    new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 3, 8)),
                    new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 3, 8)),
                    new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 10)),
                    new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 12, 10)),
                    new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 5)),
                    new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 25)),
                    new NewBorn(LocalDate.of(2021, 7, 12)));

    System.out.println(dateInWitchMostChildrenAreBorn(newBorns));
}
```

**Output** (*expected* : three dates on which the number of newborns is `2`)

```
[2021-12-10, 2021-03-08, 2021-01-05]
```